# How do i transfer a string that starts with the specified character into another column in sparksql

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given the dataframe below:

```
Row|Address                                                                 |Contact      |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|1  |J. Borja cor. Guillermo St., Cagayan de Oro City 08822 722-922 / 726-667|null         |
|2  |Cruz Taal cor. Apolinar Velez St.,Cagayan de Oro City 08822 725-301     |null         |
|3  |R.N. Abejuela St., Cagayan de Oro City                                  |08822 727-864|
```

How do i convert it into this:

```
Row|Address                                                      |Contact                  |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|1  |J. Borja cor. Guillermo St., Cagayan de Oro City            | 08822 722-922 / 726-667 |
|2  |Cruz Taal cor. Apolinar Velez St.,Cagayan de Oro City       |           08822 725-301 |
|3  |R.N. Abejuela St., Cagayan de Oro City                      |           08822 727-864 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use regular expressions to extract `Contact_tmp` from `Address`, then erase it from `Address`, and finally use `coalesce`function to merge `Contact` and `Contact_tmp`.

```
df = df.withColumn('Contact_tmp', F.regexp_extract('Address', '\\d+\\s+\\d+-\\d+\\s*/*\\s*\\d*-*\\d*', 0)).select(
    'Row',
    F.expr('replace(Address, Contact_tmp, "")').alias('Address'),
    F.coalesce('Contact', 'Contact_tmp').alias('Contact')
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```